# How to rollback save on failure of another save in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, transactions, rails-activerecord

I have a scenario where I would update Model1 on loop and after the loop is over I would save Model2 but I need to rollback the update on failure of the Model2 save

```
@var1 = Model1.new
@var1.model2 = @var2

(1..5).each do |value|
  if (condition)
    @var1.send("field#{value}_st") = val1
    @var1.send("field#{value}_nd") = val2
    @var1.send("field#{value}_rd") = val3

    @var2.update_attributes(f1 => val4)
  end   
end

if @var1.save
 ....
 ....
else
 rollback
end
```

So I want to rollback the update of @var2 on failure of the @var1.save. How can I do this using active record transaction?

Comment: Is it possible to save var2 AFTER var1 saves succesfully?

Comment: I have previously used that approach of saving var2 after var1 but now I was supposed to save it before var1. Thats why I need this rollback.

Comment: Do you have to keep `@var2` inside the loop?

Comment: Yes, definitely. I actually check with a condition and if it satisfies, then i would update else I would continue the loop. Otherwise, i need to check the condition outside the loop separately another time. I have edited the code.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach would be to use ActiveRecord::Transactions

Think about a finacial transaction as an example where one insertion must be rolled back if a subsequent insertion fails.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  david.withdrawal(100)
  mary.deposit(100)
end
```

Try this with your existing inserts. I *think* this is what you're after

```
@var1 = Model1.new
@var1.model2 = @var2

ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do

  (1..5).each do |value|
    @var1.send("field#{value}_st") = val1
    @var1.send("field#{value}_nd") = val2
    @var1.send("field#{value}_rd") = val3

    @var2.update_attributes(f1 => val4)   
  end
  @var1.save
end
```